# How to get Vulkan context from X11 window in C?

Tags: c, x11, vulkan

I'm trying to create a Vulkan application in Linux. How can I obtain a Vulkan context from a raw X11 window, no Qt or GTK involved.

Thanks :)

Comment: Um. Plenty of questions demonstrate a simple example of something. I don't think it's an unreasonable question to ask how to create an X11 window and get a Vulkan context from it, especially since Vulkan is so new and not learner-friendly, and such topics are the point of Stack Exchange. Furthermore, every Vulkan tutorial I've managed to find just uses GLFW3--I want to know what it does behind-the-scenes for an X11 window.

Comment: Moderators have a little diamond next to their names. However, moderators aren't the only ones who moderate content, and there's nothing self-proclaimed about it -- there's a reason we have a [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reputation) system here.

Comment: Is my question reasonable now?

Comment: @SamClaus It is not "broad" anymore. It lacks research effort though. GLFW is open-source. Even if it wasn't, it doesn't hide anything surprising regarding to your question. It just chooses the appropriate `vkCreate*SurfaceKHR` for the chosen platform.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you already got your X11 window you need to define `VK_USE_PLATFORM_XLIB_KHR` and create a Vulkan compatible surface from it using `vkCreateXlibSurfaceKHR`, or if you want to use XCB you'd use `vkCreateXcbSurfaceKHR` and define `VK_USE_PLATFORM_XCB_KHR`.

Also note that you need to provide the proper surface extension at instance creation time. Either `VK_KHR_XLIB_SURFACE_EXTENSION_NAME` or `VK_KHR_XCB_SURFACE_EXTENSION_NAME`.

You then provide that surface at swapchain creation time (given your application does some visible output).

See [the WSI chapter of the spec for details](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0-wsi_extensions/html/vkspec.html#_wsi_surface).